# PHP: The country and continent for a given location

Tags: php, location, generator, country

Based on a given location, I have to generate the country and the continent belonging to it.

Ex. For Nuernberg, I need to generate "Germany, Europe".

I am wondering if there is a library I can use or if I need to do it "manually".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using world.sql

Reference:

http://dimitrik.free.fr/mysqltechday_2013_10/world.sql

To import list of continents, into your mysql database and then building a php program using that.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.